# populate table with while loop

Tags: php

I'm trying to populate a table pulling data from my MySQL db, there's 3 entries in the database, but for some reason echoing the data doesn't work, although I can see that it's going through the loop 3 times (the table creates 3 checkboxes, 1 for each entry)

Code

```
<?php 
    $qry2="SELECT * FROM buytraff WHERE username='$username'";
    $result2=mysql_query($qry2) or die(mysql_error()); 
    while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)):?>

<tr class="first">
<td class="tc">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="tc"><center><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"></font><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><? echo $rows['id']; ?></font>
</center></td>
<td class="tc"><center><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><? echo $rows['url']; ?></font></center></td>

<td><center><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><? echo $rows['nichecountry']; ?></font></center></td>
<td class="tc"><center><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php if($rows['type']=='1.99'){
echo "something";
}

elseif($rows['type']=='2.99'){
echo "something";
}

elseif($rows['type']=='3.00'){
echo "something";
}

elseif($rows['type']=='4.00'){
echo "something";
}

?></font></center></td>
<td class="tc"><center><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><? echo $rows['price']; ?> $</font></center></td>
<td class="tc"><center><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><? echo $rows['amount']; ?></font></center></td>
<td class="tc"><center><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><? echo $rows['delivered']; ?></font></center></td>
<td class="tc"><center><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><? echo $rows['status']; ?></font></center></td>
<td class="tc"><center><input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="checkbox[]" value="<? echo $rows['id']; ?>"></center></td> 
</tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: you should really go about learning css. The <font> tag has been deprecated a long time ago

Comment: @PraveenKumar What do you mean ? If you mean what's happening, then nothing. That's the problem. It creates the checkboxes though from `<td class="tc"><center><input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="checkbox[]" value="<? echo $rows['id']; ?>"></center></td>`

Comment: It works now, for some reason Xampp doesn't like `<? bla ?>` after changing the it to `<?php blabla ?>` it's working correcly.

Comment: @HansKohler `<? ?>` are PHP short tags, you should not use it, `<?php ?>` is recommended for portability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Using PHP Short Tags

In XAMPP, you need to enable this option in `PHP.ini`:

```
short_open_tag = On
```